# How to use a .h library of C++ in a program writen by C#?

Tags: c#, c++

i am writing a program in C# which generates a text file containing the information of a Graph, i like to find its K-Cores,

i have found a C++ library to do that, but i don't know how to use it.

the name of the library is Kcore.h and i put it in the same folder of my project.

but how to pass my text file to it and call it's KCore function?

KCore.h is one of the libraries of SNAP project which can be accessed at http://snap.stanford.edu/snap/

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kcore.h is just a header file.  You will need to build the library as a dll first then use the C# external dll import feature to use the routines.  The link you have given, doesn't provide libraries:  you will need to create a solution to build it: look at the makefile for help.

Comment: actually i did that already, it created a kcore.exe file, is that it?

Comment: @RmanEdv, you're missing the second part of cup's sentence.  Once you have a dll (or exe) you need to import it (use the C# external dll import feature) into your c# app.